# This function has a return type of 'Widget', but doesn't end with a return statement. Build widget returning error

Tags: flutter

I have the following warning => This function has a return type of 'Widget', but doesn't end with a return statement. (Documentation)  Try adding a return statement, or changing the return type to 'void'.

When I add the return statement in the void function, I encounter the following error:

A value of type 'void' can't be returned from the method 'build' because it has a return type of 'Widget'. (Documentation)

```
   [...]else if (state is CancelOrderErrorState) {
          showCoreMessageSnackBar(
            CoreMessageWidget.error(title: strings.cancelOrderFailureText.localize(context)),
            autoDismiss: true,
          );
    [...]
```

Can someone help me fix this return statement?

Comment: you will have to return a widget in the build method,

Comment: But I want to return a void

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand your code a little bit:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
...
    else if (state is CancelOrderErrorState) {
          showCoreMessageSnackBar(
            CoreMessageWidget.error(title: strings.cancelOrderFailureText.localize(context)),
            autoDismiss: true,
          );
        return Container(); //<--add this
    }
...
}
```

You HAVE to return what the method is defined to return which is a Widget. Since the build method is overridden you can't change the return type. Sometimes returning something simple is all you can do.